# C++ program to output a list of pairs of the form L:N where L is a line number and N is the number of occurrences of the given word

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  ifstream inflie(argv[1]);
  int currentLine = 1;
  vector<string> words;
  map<vector<string>, int> freq;
  string line;
  while (getline(infile, line)) {
    istringstream inputString(line);
    currentLine++
    string word;
    while(inputString >> word){
      words.push_back(pair(word, currentLine));
      freq[words]++;
  }
  map<vector<string>, int>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter=freq.begin(); iter != freq.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this is what I have so far.  Its giving me multiple errors when I try to compile.  please keep in mind that last c++ stuff I did was in highschool nearly two years ago.  I really have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.

Here are my errors (this is really sad):

```
tabulate.cc: In function `int main(int, const char**)':
tabulate.cc:11: error: `vector' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:11: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
tabulate.cc:11: error: `words' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:12: error: `vector' cannot appear in a constant-expression
tabulate.cc:12: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
/usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.9/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_map.h:92: error: provided for `template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map'
tabulate.cc:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
tabulate.cc:12: error: expected unqualified-id before "int"
tabulate.cc:14: error: `infile' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:15: error: variable `std::istringstream inputString' has initializer but incomplete type
tabulate.cc:17: error: expected `;' before "string"
tabulate.cc:18: error: `word' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:19: error: missing template arguments before '(' token
tabulate.cc:20: error: `freq' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:20: warning: unused variable 'freq'
tabulate.cc:22: error: `vector' cannot appear in a constant-expression
tabulate.cc:22: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
/usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.9/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_map.h:92: error: provided for `template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map'
tabulate.cc:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
tabulate.cc:22: error: expected unqualified-id before "int"
tabulate.cc:23: error: `iter' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:23: error: `freq' was not declared in this scope
tabulate.cc:14: warning: unused variable 'infile'
tabulate.cc:27: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include those multiple errors. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Your program has obvious mistakes like `inflie` != `infile`, you don't `#include <vector>` nor `<sstream>`.  You should start with a simpler program that's able to read the lines - `cout` them back to the display so you can check it's working, then build things up gradually, keeping it compiling and well-understood.